# Is there any script i can run on the terminal that downloads all the releases on my desktop

Tags: github, github-api, github-for-mac

Is there any script i can run on the terminal that downloads all the releases on my desktop. I am trying to download all the releases and download on my computer.

Here is the information on how to do the latest releases - https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/a4cd19cda655b8249d908261a62687f8

However, i would like to download all

Here is something i found but not sure if it will download all the releases - https://gist.github.com/maxim/6e15aa45ba010ab030c4

Comment: What do you mean by "download all the releases"?  How would this differ from cloning the repo?

Comment: @jmargolisvt, here is the information on how to do the latest release - https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/a4cd19cda655b8249d908261a62687f8

Comment: however, i would like to do all of it